# client denied by server configuration: website_c.wsgi, referer: http://website_b.com/

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm not a sysadmin, but I do my best, so apologies in advance for my ignorance.

I run a linux server with apache2 on it. I have 3 websites I am trying to host on it, but the sites-enabled/000-default.conf file must be misconfigured.

Basically, website_c seems to be preventing website_b from showing up, as per the error message in the title. website_a and website_c show up correctly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ghost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # Servers to proxy the connection, or
    # List of application servers Usage
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:2369/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2369/
    ServerName website_a.com
    ServerAlias www.website_a.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName website_b.com:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website_b
    ServerAlias www.website_b.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName website_c.com:80
        ServerAlias .*
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/python_envs/production/website_c/apache/production-website_c.wsgi 
        <Directory /home/username/python_envs/production>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/python_envs/production/website_c/apache/production-website_c.wsgi 
WSGIPythonHome /home/username/python_envs/production
WSGIPythonPath /home/username/python_envs/production/website_c

Alias /rgc-dev/static/ /home/username/python_envs/dev/website_c-static/

WSGIScriptAlias /rgc-dev /home/username/python_envs/dev/website_c/apache/dev-website_c.wsgi

Alias /rgc-staging/static/ /home/username/python_envs/staging/website_c-static/

WSGIScriptAlias /rgc-staging /home/username/python_envs/staging/project_container/website_c/apache/staging-website_c.wsgi

Alias /rgc-production/static/ /home/username/python_envs/production/website_c-static/

WSGIScriptAlias /rgc-prod /home/username/python_envs/production/website_c/apache/production-website_c.wsgi
```

The error message in the apache log when I try to access website_b is: client denied by server configuration: /home/username/python_envs/production/website_c/apache/production-website_c.wsgi, referer: http://website_b.com/

Can anyone spot the issue with my apache conf? Please let me know if you need me to post the production-website_c.wsgi, I can't see anything that looks relevant there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this was the problem: 
`WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/python_envs/production/website_c/apache/production-website_c.wsgi`

I commented out that line and website_c was still displaying correctly, so there ya go.